# jQuery Chosen displaying without its css

Tags: jquery, html, css, laravel, jquery-chosen

I am using this plugin https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ to turn a normal dropdown field into a searchable list. However, the jquery chosen field is not displaying properly, it loads without the css.

[image]

I've placed the css in `public/assets/css/` and js in `public/assets/js` - I've included the png sprites in the css folder.

This is my code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/chosen.min.css') }}">
<script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/chosen.jquery.min.js') }}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".chosen-select").chosen();
  });
</script>

<p>
   {!! Form::label('subreddit', 'Subreddit:') !!}
   {!! Form::select('subreddit_id', $subreddits, null, ['class' => 'chosen-select', 'id' => 'subreddit_id']) !!}
</p>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the css is loading, I've checked the html source code and it's there, the link is valid also, if I click on it, it will load the css.

Comment: have you added reference to `jquery-*.js` file?? not `choesn.jquery.js` before adding link to chosen.js you need to add `jquery-*.js` any latest version of `jquery`.. You might be getting some console errors if you check..

Comment: I also have a link to `jquery.min.js` and `jquery-ui.min.js`

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle please?

Comment: None, submitting to the database even works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/chosen.min.css') }}">
```

When loading a CSS you need to use the `href` attribute

Comment: what a catch... +1. :)

Comment: I'm gonna go shoot myself in the foot now. Thank you very much, that solved it.

Comment: happens all the time :)